# How to track cause of blocking IO problems

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer, io

I move between multiple subnets and networks on a regular basis.  I'm often faced with Explorer and other programs that stall in what appears to be an IO request.  I'm trying to find a consistent way to track which request is stalling.  Tools like process explorer don't provide the information that I need.

Additionally, is there a registry setting I can use to reduce the timeout period ?

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about a Windows OS here (my guess from the Explorer mention). If so, one thing that'll help: Visit Folder Options, the View tab and uncheck "Automatically search for network folders and printers." and see if that helps things out a bit.

As for tools, have you tried Proc Mon as well? 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: I wasn't aware of that setting, but it didn't have any affect.  I'm familiar with ProcMon and it shows resources active per process, but it doesn't tell you which of those resources are causing blocking IO.